# Convert type "language" to "expression"

Tags: r, plot, expression, curve, coercion

I am new to R, and I am often confused by data structures that either don't exist or I don't have a need for in other languages.

At the moment, I am trying to convert an object of type "language" to "expression" so that I can plot it.

First I create the function I want to plot:

```
> model <- nls(y~a+b*exp(x*z),start = list(a=1, b = -.5, z = -.8),data=results)  
> modelsym <- substitute(a+b*exp(z*x), list(a=coef(model[1],b=coef(model)[2],z=coef(model)[3]))
```

The function is of type "language":

```
> modelsym  
0.958945264470923 + -0.463676594301167 * exp(-0.155697065390677 * x)  
> typeof(modelsym)  
[1] "language"
```

If I try to plot this curve:

```
> curve(modelsym)  
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "modelsym"
```

However if I copy and paste it works fine:

```
> curve(0.958945264470923 + -0.463676594301167 * exp(-0.155697065390677 * x))  
**[plot appears here]**
```

I've tried `as(modelsym,expression)` to no avail.

How can I convert my object `modelsym` to an `expression` in order to plot it?

Comment: Can you show exactly how `modelsym` was created? Just so we are working with exactly the same thing.

Comment: @GavinSimpson sure, i just edited my original question

Comment: FYI I just figured out a work-around: `plot(eval(modelsym),type='line')` works, but would still like to know the answer to my original question...

Answer (score 3):

This is not a full solution but I have got close with:

```
do.call(curve, list(expr = modelsym))
```

which essentially arranges for the call to `curve` for you with the `expr` argument set to the content of `modelsym`.

The reason what you are trying fails is that the first line of `curve` is

```
sexpr <- substitute(expr)
```

which gives this when passed an object containing a statement (well any object, really) results in:

```
Browse[2]> sexpr
modelsym
Browse[2]> is.call(sexpr)
[1] FALSE
Browse[2]> is.expression(sexpr)
[1] FALSE
```

and those two tests are what `curve` uses to see if the input is acceptable.

Whatever you pass `curve` it needs to be an actual statement and not a call containing one.

Comment: I think that's a bug in `curve`, since any time you pass in an object to expr, `is.name(sexpr)` will be true.  Also you're using expression in two slightly incompatible ways. Colloquially, an expression a quoted (unevalated) call, but that's not what `is.expression` tests for (in a similar way to `is.vector` not testing if an object is a vector)

Comment: +1 for the solution, though I agree with Hadley that talking about expressions here (and especially testing for one with `is.expression`) is possibly misleading because of its several meanings in this context. (Even the R documentation is occasionally confusing in this regard.)

Comment: I only showed the output from `is.expression` as that is what `curve` uses as a test on the substituted input, but I agree the terminology is confusing. Thanks for your comments, both.

Comment: @hadley I seem what you mean and have changed the usage to "statement" or "expression object", which I think is more strictly correct?

Comment: @GavinSimpson -- I think those are good terms to use. [R-lang](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Language-objects) does something similar, saying that, "in particular syntactically correct expressions will be referred to as statements". In the final line of your post, I'd edit "not an expression object ..." to something like "not a symbol containing one as its value" b/c `modelsym` is not itself an expression object. Instead, it's a symbol whose value is an expression object. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks for this, a thoughtful comment. In thinking on this some more and creating something akin to what the OP has, `modelsym` is a call (mode "call"). It isn't a symbol in the sense of `is.symbol`.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting because it's so hard to speak about with precision. I do think `modelsym` "is" a symbol in the sense of `is.symbol` and in the sense that `<-` "assigns a value to a name" (where "name" is a synonym for "symbol", see also `is.name`). Sure, `mode(modelsym)` returns `"call"`, but `x <- 1:9; mode(x)` returns `"numeric"`, even though `x` clearly is a symbol. Better in this case to test `mode(quote(modelsym))` or `is.symbol(quote(modelsym))`, where `quote()` prevents `modelsym`'s evaluation to its value.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative plan of attack is to use predict:

```
model <- nls(y~a+b*exp(x*z),start = list(a=1, b = -.5, z = -.8),data=results)

modelf <- function(x) predict(model, newdata = data.frame(x = x))
plot(modelf)
curve(modelf)
```